# Does the VPN provider will have access to my content?

Tags: tls, vpn

I am planning to buy a VPN service just to circumvent the filtering applied by the government. However as I am planning to use OpenVPN on my dd-wrt router, all of my data will pass through this tunnel. My question is that if it is possible for the provider to go through my data. If so, is it also true about the SSL connections like https as well?

Answer (score 1):

A VPN will provide a secure tunnel between the device running the VPN client (your dd-wrt router) and the VPN server (hosted by your VPN provider). All traffic that gets routed through the tunnel will be reasonably secure against monitoring and tampering, but only while its in the tunnel.

On either end of the tunnel, it is still vulnerable. The VPN provider will be able to monitor all of the traffic as it passes in and out of their end of the tunnel, just as your dd-wrt router will be able to monitor the traffic as it passes in and out of its end.

A VPN is only useful if:

- You trust the network and/or device running the VPN client
- You trust the VPN server
- The adversary you wish to protect yourself from is thought to be somewhere between the two

The same goes for HTTPS and anything else that uses SSL/TLS.